# Most links to ruby-doc.org seem broken

Tags: bug, status-norepro

While browsing stackoverflow I have noticed multiple broken links to the ruby-doc.org website.

[Example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21070923/9785060)

[Example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/198470/9785060)(First link)

In the first example the original link is `http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Kernel.html#method-i-rand` but after opening it in my browser is becomes : `https://ruby-doc.org/https://ruby-doc.org//core-2.1.3/Kernel.html#method-i-rand` and I get this error message:

> We're sorry, but that page cannot be found.

Removing the additional part the browser adds (the double https://ruby-doc.org/ in the link) or adding an `s` before the `http` part of the link before accessing the link solves the issue. But I think this might be a global problem because because ruby-docs.org have a secure protocol now (not sure that's the reason, just guessing). I'm getting the same result in both Firefox and Chrome.

I can not edit these questions since it's only a single character that's broken, yet it causes a lot of answers to be invalid.

Edit: The first link seems to be fixed meanwhile, but I'm not sure if that's the solution to the issue as it seems global, not just related to a single question.

Comment: I edited the 2 link and this: https://ruby-doc.org//core-2.1.3/Kernel.html#method-i-rand worked fine

Comment: Not sure what exactly are you saying, but the second link works fine now because it's been edited after I posted the question here. I explained that in the Edit part of my question.

Comment: `http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Kernel.html#method-i-rand` redirects to `https://ruby-doc.org//core-2.1.3/Kernel.html#method-i-rand` now. Looks like they noticed the issue. I do see there is two slashes at the beginning.

Comment: @KyleK I sent them an email yesterday, they responded quickly and solved the issue. Everything looks fine now

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is something that goes wrong at the ruby-doc.org site and I'm not sure SE is the party that needs to fix this:

[image]

An url search [gives over 7,000 hits for that domain](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.ruby-doc.org&mixed=0). If anything, this warrants an automatic url rewrite by the Community user but only after someone did reach out to ruby-doc.org asking them to fix their URL rewrite to https logic. If they decline or are unable to fix that issue it is time to consider our options.

Comment: I will write them an e-mail with a short explanation of the issue and a link to this question. It should be enough I think. I guess the problem is (kinda?) solved and I can accept this answer, if you agree.

Comment: @Виктор thanks. Just wait till you have a response and then decide if this answer has still merit. Don't accept an answer too early. There is no rush.